# C# Windows IoT Core Background Application Assembly Binding Redirects

Tags: windows, binding, .net-assembly, iot

I am setting up my first Windows IoT Core background application that is running on a Raspberry Pi, but I am running into a problem with conflicting assembly versions and I have been unable to resolve them.

Specifically, I am getting an error message that states:

```
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Data.Common, Version=4.2.1.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Data.Common, 
Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing 
"System.Data.Common, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
```

Upon closer inspection, there are two versions of the `System.Data.Common.dll` that my application is referencing.

The first is coming from the installed package `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (v 6.2.8)`.  The assembly version of System.Data.Common here is 4.2.1.0 (which is the version I want to use):

```
Assembly System.Data.Common version 4.2.1.0

C:\Users\mikel\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform\6.2.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Data.Common.dll
```

The second is apparently being included as a dependency with the .netstandard:

```
Assembly System.Data.Common version 4.1.0.0

C:\Users\mikel\.nuget\packages\System.Data.Common\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.2\System.Data.Common.dll
```

I am having a little harder time pinpointing exactly what is forcing NuGet to download and install the second package.  Perhaps one of my other packages that I need is referencing it as a dependency (not sure).

**Either way, I would like to setup assembly binding remapping so that any attempt to reference 4.1.0.0 will redirect and use 4.2.1.0.**

When I do a build of my project, I get this warning:

```
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Data.Common, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.1.0.0" 
[C:\Users\mikel\.nuget\packages\System.Data.Common\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.2\System.Data.Common.dll] 
to Version "4.2.1.0" 
[C:\Users\mikel\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform\6.2.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Data.Common.dll] 
to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
```

However from what I have read, Universal Windows Projects do not support the use of app.config files.  At any rate though, I added an app.config file to the root of my project, set the build action to `Embedded Resource`, selected `Copy Always` and put this in the file (to no affect):

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.Common" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I have also tried setting the NuGet project management format to `PackageReference` and added `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` to each PropertyGroup in my .csproj file.  This did not have any impact.

My Universal Windows project targets are as follows:

**Target version:** `Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299)`

**Minimum Version:** `Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299)`

I should also state that I *want* to use the 4.2.1.0 version of the assembly, as 4.1.0.0 is missing a few things I need to implement the wrapper I am using around SQLite.  My preference is to not have to re-write those wrappers.

At this point I am very confused as to how to resolve this conflict.  How do I enable binding redirects to resolve this error?

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what nuget packages you have installed for your background application? And what are their versions?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT --

Microsoft.Data.Sqlite (v1.1.0);
Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (v6.2.8);
SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green (v1.1.13)

Comment: I use same nuget packages with same version of yours and same target and minimum version, but I can't reproduce your issue. Please show related code for reproducing this issue.

Comment: You can try [Reference Conflicts Analyser](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MykolaTarasyuk.ReferenceConflictsAnalyser) tool for visual studio to find how the conflict happens.

Comment: So I was able to resolve this. When I went to installed the Reference Conflicts Analyser, I noticed that my build of Studio 2017 was outdated.  So I updated to the latest build - and low and behold, it magically started working.  No idea at all why, but problem resolved!  Thanks so much for helping take a look at this.